# Using java to create excel file with a web query link

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I want to create excel file from java (for example with Apache POI) that contains web query with link to my application but I couldn't find any reference for it. Is that possible? 
I'll even settle for updating the link of a web query in an existing excel file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What I finally did is to create an xlsx file with a temp connection. Then I opened the file using a zip reader and modified the connections.xml file inside and then I zipped the file again to xlsx.

Works like a charm.

Comment: will you please share some code samples.  I am stuck on this! Thanks.